# Highcharts Not Exporting Unicode Characters Visible On HTML Chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am faced with a bit of a conundrum. I have a chart that renders correctly on the web page itself with desired unicode accent characters (think Spanish, but some English words as well). The DOM shows these characters correctly and the SVG includes them. All is good. But, when I attempt to export these charts to our node.js-based export server provided by highcharts I get the dreaded diamond "?" symbols all over the place. If I copy this entire chart logic with its dependent HTML table it reads from outside our enterprise application and export (again, to our local node server) it renders correctly.

**What would prevent a perfectly rendered chart from being exported with the correct character encoding?**

Example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/19r78taw/) with sample of our data and how we create from HTML table.

Code we use to export (we do not use the built-in hamburger menu):

```
function chartExportSwitch(chartid, exportSelect, graphHeader, graphFooter, marginSize) {
    var type = 'image/jpeg';

    switch ($(exportSelect).val()) {
        case 'JPEG':
            type = 'image/jpeg';
            break;
        case 'PNG':
            type = 'image/png';
            break;
        case 'SVG':
            type = 'image/svg+xml';
            break;
        case 'PDF':
            type = 'application/pdf';
            break;
    }

    chartExportLoc(chartid, type, graphHeader, graphFooter, marginSize);

    $(exportSelect).slideToggle('fast');
}

function chartExportLoc(chartid, exportType, graphHeader, graphFooter, marginSize) {
    var chartToExport = $('#' + chartid).highcharts();

    var sourceSpacingBottom = chartToExport.options.chart.spacingBottom;
    if (!marginSize) {
        marginSize = 15;    //HighCharts default
    }

    chartToExport.exportChart(
        {
            type: exportType,
            scale: 1,
            filename: chartid
        },
        {
            title: { text: graphHeader, margin: marginSize },
            subtitle: { y: 10, text: graphFooter },
            chart: { shadow: false, width: 800, spacingBottom: sourceSpacingBottom - 20 }
        });

    return false;
}
```

My initial thought was that I could modify the items upon export to do stuff like:

```
if (chartToExport.xAxis[0].categories != undefined) {
    for (index = 0; index < chartToExport.xAxis[0].categories.length; ++index) {
        chartToExport.xAxis[0].categories[index] = unescape(encodeURI(chartToExport.xAxis[0].categories[index]));
    }
}
```

This seems to work but, of course, it modifies the existing chart on the page as well - which results in some interesting text artifacts.

So, I attempted to clone my highcharts object within the export code but this still only appears to have references to deep items instead of actually copying/cloning because if I make the `categories` change mentioned above on my `chartClone` object it still modifies the original chart:

```
var chartToExport = $('#' + chartid).highcharts();
var chartToExport = jQuery.extend(true, {}, $('#' + chartid).highcharts());
```

I have also tried the following but got error on circular objects:

```
var chartClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chartToExport));
```

I also tried the Highcharts.merge() method:

```
var origChart = $('#' + chartid).highcharts();
var chartToExport = Highcharts.merge(false, origChart);
```

This results in exceeding the callstack
**So, a follow-up question would be how to deep copy a highcharts object?**

Comment: Regarding the **deep clone** question: Why don't you just create a new chart using the same options as the original one?

Comment: Because a user could hide/show available series or change zoom, etc. Deep clone of the current chart "as it is now" is what I need.

Comment: Every chart has `options` object that contains merged user options (passed to the chart constructor) and Highcharts default values. You can perform a deep copy of this object and create a new chart using it. Unfortunately not all user actions are saved in `options` e.g. extremes of the chart (zoom). On the other hand series visibility is remembered and works fine. **Live demo** I used for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/8nj4h5se/ If you have a limited and precisely defined set of actions that user can perform, setting some options manually on the duplicated chart shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I see you are using `lodash` to accomplish this - this is not an option for us in our enterprise. If you see my notes I have tried other deep copy attempts and all failed with exceeding the callstack.

Comment: It seems to work fine (http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/pp1xpe86/) when I try to deep clone only `options` object like this: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chart1.options));`

Comment: Try with my sample chart.

Comment: I did as you said: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/jkracbq7/ Seems to work fine.

Comment: I do not see anything about merging in your linked fiddle for exporting.

Comment: Merging of what?

Comment: Sorry, I meant deep copy - I see my Highcharts.merge() statement used to generate the chart from default options and the data from the table. But nothing regarding JSON.parse.

Comment: What about this code?: `var chart1 = charts[charts.length] = new Highcharts.Chart(options),
             options2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(chart1.options)),
       chart2 = Highcharts.chart('container2', options2);`

Comment: take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/19r78taw/2/. The `$("#btnExport").bind('click', function(event) {` code is what i am trying to accomplish.

Comment: To sum up: you want to have the exact copy of the chart so that you can edit it before exporting without modifying the original?

Comment: Correct - or find out why the chart is not rendering unicode when exported.

Comment: So the steps that I proposed seem to be the way: At first create a deep copy of options object only. Then create a new chart using the cloned options and apply the changes that need to be done manually (e.g. extremes (take them from the original chart)). Modify the chart and export it. What's wrong with this solution?

Comment: It throws error as I described in my question - callstack exceeded.

Comment: I moved the code from my previous fiddles to the `btnExport` and everything seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/yLbq1h87/